# incrementing a value in Neo4j cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

A user is passing me an array of UUID that refer to nodes in my database. I want to related her USER node to each of these other nodes. The challenge is, I want to know the order in which the UUIDs were given to me.

So if the UUIDs are: [AAA, CCC, BBB], I want to execute something like:

```
(user)-[:REL {order: 1}]->(:THING {name:"AAA"})
(user)-[:REL {order: 2}]->(:THING {name:"CCC"})
(user)-[:REL {order: 3}]->(:THING {name:"BBB"})
```

Of course, I don't want to do it in multiple statements. I want to pass that list as a parameter.

```
MATCH(u:USER {id:{id}})
MATCH(t:THING) where t.name in {that_list}
CREATE (u)-[:REL {order: ???}]->(t)
```

Note the `???`. That's the crux.

How can this be accomplished? I have it passing tests using a loop, but I feel I ought to be able to do this.

Comment: I don't know your use cases, but have you thought about chaining the `THING` nodes together in order, so that you do not need to have the `order` properties? Like this: `(user)-[:REL]->(:THING {name:"AAA"})-[:REL]->(:THING {name:"BBB"})-[:REL]->(:THING {name:"CCC"})`?

Comment: @cybersam that's very clever. I'm not sure I can do it in my case, but it is very graphy. I like it.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
MATCH(u:USER {id:{id}})
UNWIND {that_list} AS name
MATCH(t:THING) WHERE t.name = name
WITH u, COLLECT(t) AS things
FOREACH(i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(things)-1) |
  FOREACH(x IN [things[i]] | CREATE (u)-[:REL {order: i}]->(x)));
```

The `UNWIND` makes each item in your list available in a separate data row, in the same order.

The inner `FOREACH` just "iterates" over a single node. This trick is used because the `CREATE` pattern cannot use an expression for a node. Therefore, this logically equivalent clause would not have been legal: `FOREACH(i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(things)-1) | CREATE (u)-[:REL {order: i}]->(things[i]))`.

Comment: What's the UNWIND doing? Can I not delete that line and instead change the following WHERE clause to `t.name IN {that_list}` ?

Comment: Looks like the nested FOREACH is causing n^2 relations to be created.

Comment: 1. The `UNWIND` is there to enforce the order in your list, as neo4j will create rows in the same order. The `IN` syntax does not guarantee ordering. 2. The inner `FOREACH` is just "iterating" over a single node, so the query is not `O(N^2)`. This trick is used because the `CREATE` pattern does not support nodes generated by a expression.

Comment: Man it's real close, but my test case is generating a 'cartesian' number of relations between `u` and the things.

Comment: It feels like `things[i]` has multiple things in it when of course it should not.

Comment: It is not really cartesian, since one leg only contains a single node.

Comment: I have verified that only N relationships are created.

Comment: Yep. I have a bug somewhere, and have traced it to the `size(event_types)` which is returning a value larger than I have "thing" nodes in the database. Probably something stupid in my test case.